# Активная вкладка при загрузке jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tab

Собственно, как принудительно указать, какой таб должен быть активным при загрузке страницы?

Создается объект так:
`$('.tabs').tabs({});`

В итоге есть 5 табов, с условными именами от 8 до 12.

```
<div class="tabs tabs-lockable">
    <div class="container-for-mob-slider">
        <ul class="tabs-list..
            <li><a href="#tabs-8,9,10...
```

И собственно сами табы:

```
<div class="tab-content-block" id="tabs-8,9,10...
```

Табы работают, но я не могу принудительно указать, какой таб должен быть активен при загрузке страницы. В качестве свойств для объекта `.tabs` передавал `active:` с разными значениями - индекс `0, 1, 2..`, id `tabs-...`, `#tabs-...` но все без толку. Пока промежуточным решением есть делать клик при загрузке, но он не всегда работает как ожидается, и кроме того иногда видно, что активная всегда первая вкладка, а спустя некий промежуток времени клик и переход на другую вкладку.

Comment: а где указывается номер нужной вкладки? в url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там должен применяться клас, вот его js-ом убирайте и ставьте где вам надо. если не понятно - дайте ссылку на код

Comment: для табов задаются эти классы - ui-tabs-active ui-state-active, а тело табов просто скрывается или показывается

Comment: Хм.. спасибо за совет, это немного лучше, чем подход с кликами, но не совсем "элегантно" :). Неужели нету решения, которое было бы в духе jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 2
});
```

[ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick74/CnEUh/3706/)
прекрасно работает active, в чем сложность? Версия ui последняя?